# parse HttpClientRequest response

Tags: javascript, post, httpclient

i have another novice (and probably stupid) question. i am using HttpClientRequest and making a post call. also i have the response.

```
var url = <my url>
var request = new HttpClientRequest(url);
request.header["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.method = "POST";

try
{

  request.execute();
  var rawResponse = request.response.body.toString();
}
```

the response from server is in the following format: 
{"token":"abc","expires_in":9292,"refresh":"deeDfTTgendj"}

i just need to extract "expires_in" and "refresh" fields from the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since that is valid JSON, you can parse it:

```
var rawResponse = request.response.body.toString(),
    objectLiteral = JSON.parse(rawResponse);

var expires_in = objectLiteral['expires_in'],
    refresh = objectLiteral['refresh'];
```

```js
var rawResponse = '{"token":"abc","expires_in":9292,"refresh":"deeDfTTgendj"}';
    objectLiteral = JSON.parse(rawResponse);

var expires_in = objectLiteral['expires_in'],
    refresh = objectLiteral['refresh'];

console.log(expires_in, refresh);
```

Note: check out [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Browser_compatibility) for [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: another query related to parsing only. please let me know if i should start it in a new thread instead.  now my response is a zip file that i need to save. this script  is running on server so i assume this should be allowed. i added the content-type to application/zip. but now how to parse and save response